# How implement a "observer" in Jquery without plugins?

Tags: jquery, ajax, observer-pattern

I need a implementation of http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe in Jquery?
With **"frequency**" too?

I need to a ticket for cakephp.

Thanks,
Celso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prototype [observe](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/observe) is equivalent to jquery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

so something like this in prototype:

```
$('myElement').observe('click', function(){...});
```

would be equivalent to this in jquery:

```
$('#myElement').bind('click', function(){...});
```

The actual implementation in the library is different, but this will provide a similar result. Also, in jquery you won't have to attach a bind() function on the end of your handler as jquery binds the scope automatically.

Comment: is possible set a "frequency" too?

Comment: @celsown what do you by frequency?  as in ajax?

Comment: Yes ! like each 5 seconds submit the myElement value

Comment: you'll have write an updater yourself with setInterval. call $.ajax in a function and call that function with with setInterval 

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval for more info

Answer (score 3):

in addition to

```
$('#myElement').bind('click', function(){...});
```

also take a look at

```
$(document).on('click', '#myElement', function(){...}); # jquery >= 1.7
```

which binds a `click` event to all present and even future elements - especially usefull if you want multiple objects to react on clicks or which are added dynamically. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ for a more detailed explanation.