# How to make "push notification" like facebook into my jsp web application?

Tags: java, database, jsp, notifications

I've a web application. Now i just planned to put notification system(just like Facebook). Can you please suggest me about this you know well fetching an answer after `refreshing` makes so buggy.

I googled but found that oracle provide `vertex.io` something like. But i don't understand How it can be linked by the notifications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535730/how-to-build-realtime-push-notification-feature-like-facebook-does?rq=1 ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say something with javascript and servlets, have some javascript send a get request to retrieve a news feed or something, check if it has anything new, and if it does, update the client's page

Answer (score 0):

Make a new thread, and make a while loop that checks for incoming messages from the server. Then when one is recieved, access a method in the gui to post that notification up.

Comment: That's a horrible idea, and not even possible with jsp, jsp is a server side web language for java